# ¿como mantener el estado de un icono marcado al abrir y cerrar la aplicación (flutter)?

Tags: flutter, icons

Quisiera que al ser presionado el icono "añadir a favoritos" (icons favorite) se mantenga marcado cuando cierre y vuelva abrir la aplicación. Supuse con deberia sera con SQflite o algo por el estilo pero no entiendo como implementarlo o que método debería usar para que se guarde esa estado del icono. Este es parte de mi código:

```
bool inCart;
bool isFav;

class Details extends StatefulWidget {
final Book bookObject;

 Details(this.bookObject);

@override
_DetailsState createState() => _DetailsState();
}

class _DetailsState extends State<Details> {
@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
inCart = false;
isFav = false;
super.initState();
}



@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(45),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.black87,
            size: 25,
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.black87,
              size: 25,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 25),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isFav = !isFav;

              });
            },
            child: Icon(
              isFav ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
              color: isFav ? Colors.red : Colors.black87,
              size: 25,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 25),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  body: DetailsPageBody(widget.bookObject),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(widget.bookObject),
);
}
}
```

Quisiera que si el icono "favorite" es pulsado, mantenga su estado de marcado aunque cierre la aplicación.
...........
...........
...........

Answer (score 0):

Para mantener un dato cuando la aplicación este cerrada necesitas persistencia ,como tu bien lo pensaste con lo de sqllite, al ser solo un dato quizas no necesitas una base de datos local y funcione de mejor forma con las [preferencias compartidas](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences